# Object[] arr = {1,2,[3,4,[5]],6}; is this is possible

Tags: java, arrays, object

I've been asked this question twice and i got confused either the question is correct or not. i searched and found nothing.
`Object[] arr = {1,2,[3,4,[5]],6};`
The question was to add all the objects of the above mentioned array.

Comment: Do not delete and repost questions.

Comment: @user3500198 Try it yourself the compiler will tell you if its possible.

Comment: Are you asking whether the syntax is valid (it's not), or how you could create such a structure logically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. That is not a valid syntax in Java.

You could do this though:

```
Object[] arr = new Object[] {
    new Integer(1), 
    new Integer(2),
    new Object[] {
        new Integer(3),
        new Integer(4),
        new Object[] {
            new Integer(5)
        }
    },
    new Integer(6)
};
```

In python you can do:

```
arr = [1, 2, [3,4,[5]],6];
```

In JavaScript:

```
let arr = [1, 2, [3,4,[5]],6];
```

Comment: do any other language let me do this?